# Slow MySQL query on a server with bad Key_reads / Key_read_requests ratio

Tags: mysql, windows, query-optimization

I am trying to solve an issue with slow queries running on MySQL 5.7 on Windows Server 2012. The engine is MyISAM (Please note than neither engine, nor the table structures in terms of column number can be changed).

The query in question is joining two tables:

- h_cell - it contains statistics for each object (cell) for each date. Currently the table contains 110 mil rows, 800+ columns with raw counters and its size is 256 GB
- clusters_cust - it contains cluster definitions and has 3 columns - cell, cluster name and comment. The row number is 62 k. Currently there are 2 clusters - Cluster1 with 7 k cell and Cluster2 with 55 k cells.

Table structures will be shown below.

So far by some reason MySQL server was running with low value of key_buffer_size. It was 8 MB (this is the default). The ratio 'Key_reads / Key_read_requests' was terrible - about 0.14. As far as I know the acceptable ratio it 0.01 and the optimal is 0.001. That is why I changed key_buffer_size in steps to 16 GB and then to 24 GB (the server has 64 GB physical memory). Unfortunately neither query speed improved, nor the ratio. Both remained unchanged.

Structure of 'h_cell':

```
CREATE TABLE `h_cell` (
    `Time` DATE NOT NULL,
    `eNodeB` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Cell` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `LocalCI` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Site` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Integrity` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    counter1 INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    counter2 INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ........
    PRIMARY KEY (`Cell`, `Time`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `Index 2` (`Cell`, `Time`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `eNodeB` (`eNodeB`, `LocalCI`, `Time`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `Index 4` (`Time`, `LocalCI`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `server` (`server`, `Time`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;
```

Structure of 'clusters_cust':

```
CREATE TABLE `clusters_cust` (
    `Cell` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `Cluster` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `Comment` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`Cell`, `Cluster`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `Cell` (`Cell`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `Cluster` (`Cluster`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `Index 4` (`Cluster`, `Comment`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `Index 5` (`Comment`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

(you can note above that this table is InnoDB. Changing it to MyISAM to match the other table didn't help)

The query:

```
select cluster,time,
round(sum(counter1)/sum(counter1+counter2)*100,2) as Avail,
...................
from h_cell
left join clusters_cust on clusters_cust.cell = h_cell.cell
where cluster='Cluster1' and  Time>='2023-08-01 00:00:00' and Time<='2023-10-02 00:00:00'
group by time
```

The result set has 19 columns, which are formulas and are using in total 43 raw counters from the 800+ in h_cell table. The rows are 63, representing each date in the reporting period.

Explain statement:

```
id  select_type table               type    possible_keys                           key         key_len     ref                 rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      clusters_cust       ref     PRIMARY,Cell,Cluster,Index 4            Cluster     242         const               12232   100         Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      h_cell              ref     PRIMARY,Index 2,eNodeB,Index 4,server   Index 2     62          clusters_cust.Cell  1055    11.15       Using index condition
```

The query time of Cluster1 (7000 objects) is about 22 min and the time for Cluster2 (55.000 objects) is 34 min.

I was monitoring the memory usage in Windows' Resource Manager. For 'mysqld' service the 'Commited memory' is 25 GB (I guess this represent the key_buffer_size of 24 GB), but the 'Private memory' is about 5 GB during query execution (in fact it remained the same after query was finished).

Any suggestions what could be wrong in the above configuration and what else can be changed in terms of system variables will be highly appreciated.

Just to mention that MySQL server installation became messy in one moment. Windows cannot start anymore the MySQL service, so this is done manually with 'mysqld' and shutting down with 'mysqladmin'. Also when starting the service manually it is complaining that file 'ibdata1' must be writable, so the solution was to grant permissions to the 'datadir' of the MySQL server to Everyone.

Comment: @ErgestBasha the Explain result is posted in the question.

Comment: Did you preload the indexes used by the query into the key buffer? If you don't, then it may take some time to see any improvement, and the first time you run the query will still have to hit the disk. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-preloading.html (index preloading only applies to the MyISAM key buffer, there is no command to preload indexes for InnoDB, you just have to let it happen by running the query).

Comment: Even given the size of your data, 22 or more minutes to run this query is ridiculous. I suspect you have something else dragging down performance on your Windows server. Can you test it with the same dataset on a different physical server?

Comment: Another question: What kind of storage is the data directory on? Is it local to the Windows server, or is it on a mapped drive or SMB share or something like that?

Comment: A DDL question: the collations on your PK and other indexed columns all use case-insensitive Unicode. That make your server work hard. Does your data allow changing those collations to `latin1_bin`? That is, are your cell and cluster values made up of 8 bit case sensitive characters? If so, changing those collations will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a so-called [covering index](http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/covering-indexes.html) on your `h_cell` table. The index I suggest here is designed to satisfy your particular example query and won't necessarily work elsewhere.

```sql
CREATE INDEX cover1 ON h_cell(cluster, time, cell, counter1, counter2);
```

Your query can get everything it needs from this index's data structure without having to read all the data in your table.

You should include all the raw counters you need for your complete query in this covering index.

Because your table's rows are so long, this will save your server a lot of I/O when satisfying your query. Because you filter on equality on `cluster`, then on a `time` range, the server won't have to scan the entire index to get what it needs.

And, the index data, being BTREE-organized, is in the right order to satisfy your query without a whole mess of sorting.

Make sure both tables use the same storage engine, and that the columns mentioned in your join's ON clause have *precisely* the same definition.

And, it's not obvious from your example why you JOIN the second table. But your LEFT JOIN does have the potential of double-summing some rows from your first table, if rows in your first table match multiple rows in the second one. So be careful.